# function space in comma category

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Let **TOP** be a category of topological spaces and **B** be an object of **TOP**. Is there a notion of function space in the comma category **TOP/B**.

Comment: Can you make "notion of function space" precise?  Or do you want a list of the various notions?  

Comment: Is the "comma" $TOP/B$ the same thing as the "slice" $TOP/B$?

Comment: You say "a" category of topological spaces. There are several ways one might interpret what you mean, but it almost sounds as if you want a full subcategory of $Top$ (ordinary topological spaces) such that every slice $Top/B$ admits function spaces in the sense of being cartesian closed. Or in other words, a full subcategory of $Top$ that is locally cartesian closed. In any case, please explain why you use the word "a". 

Comment: Andrej: presumably.  I've heard lots of people say "comma category $C/c$" where "slice category $C/c$" would be more specific.  Of course (as you know), a slice category is an example of a comma category. 

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a long history on that subject.  It is actually quite subtle point-set topology. 
The best of the original sources is a series of papers by Peter Booth.  A more recent treatment
with full details and references is in Section 1.3 of the book "Parametrized homotopy theory" by
Johann Sigurdsson and myself.  It is available at http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/EXTHEORY/MaySig.pdf. [Added] I'll say something about the choice of "a" category
$Top$.  As usual, we insist that all spaces in sight are 
$k$-spaces (compactly generated, but with no separation
property).  We insist that the base space $B$ be weak 
Hausdorff.  We cannot insist that the function space
$Map_B(X,Y)$ also be weak Hausdorff, even when the given
spaces $X$ and $Y$ over $B$ are weak Hausdorff.  Indeed,
when that holds, the map $X\longrightarrow B$ is open if and only 
if $Map_B(X,Y)$ is weak Hausdorff for all $Y\longrightarrow B$, 
by a result of Gaunce Lewis.